# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'john'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

I am trying to print second-lowest grade in a list which is like

```
students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]
```

I used the following code:

```
a = [[input(), float(input())] for i in range(int(input()))]
s = sorted(set([x[1] for x in a]))
for name in sorted(x[0] for x in a if x[1] == s[1]):
    print (name)
```

But the error which I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    a = [[input(), float(input())] for i in range(int(input()))]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'john'
```

Not sure how to get the input in the form of nested list as mentioned in `students`. Can anybody help me out with it?

Comment: The first input that is called is `range(int(input()))`, which is asking how many students long the list should be.  The error you're getting is because "john" isn't a number.

Comment: Tangential to your question, but you would find the `key` argument to `sorted` would allow you to simplify your code.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick Haugh & SpoonMeiser.

Answer (score 2):

`a = [[input(), float(input())] for i in range(int(input()))]`

In this case, the `input()` calls are performed in the following order:

```
[[input(), float(input())] for i in range(int(input()))]  
#    2           3                               1
```

You can confirm this by using prompts:

```
a = [[input('input name\n'), float(input('input grade\n'))]
     for i in range(int(input('input num of students\n')))]
```

will output:

```
>> input num of students
1
>> input name
'a'
>> input grade
1
```

So when the code runs, you first need to input a number, and not a name.

Comment: I got the output. Thank you DeepSpace!